# Como redireccionar a un formulario de la app despues de validar el usuario y contraseña en Android

Tags: php, android, eclipse

No se como explicarme pero intentare hacerlo de la mejor manera posible.

Yo he estado diseñando apps Android con la ayuda de Eclipse y Cordova. Mi app puede conectarse a una base de datos externa (web hosting). Lo que hace es verificar si el usuario existe y dar continuidad a la misma. El proceso lo realizo en PHP pero el archivo PHP se encuentra afuera del apk ya que no me funciona si lo trabajo desde ahi.

En otras palabras, primero creo el formulario iniciarsesion.html con la accion POST a www.paginaweb.com/procesoiniciarsesion.php y funciona exitosamente, ahora el problema se presenta cuando yo quiero regresar a otro formulario dentro de la app ya que como verifico desde afuera, no se como regresar a la app.

Normalmente lo que he hecho es una vez q verifico ya desde afuera, sigo con formularios de manera externa, pero quisiera que los formularios se mantuvieran en la aplicacion para evitar costes mayores en los planes de datos en moviles.

Gracias programadores

Comment: cual es tu código, tienes algo que hayas intentado para revisar lo que comentas? formularios te refieres a Web o nativo de android?

Answer (score 0):

No debes irte a un sitio externo para hacer el chequeo. Sino que debes usar el sitio externo como si fuera una API.

En archivo PHP que comprueba si existe el usuario haz que imprima OK o ERROR, para el caso de validacion correcta o incorrecta.

En la App usa Jquery o similar y haz una peticion tipo POST del siguiente modo.

Ejemplo con Jquery:

```
$(docuement).ready(function(){
  function comprobar_user(email,pass){
       $.post("paginaphpexterna",{"email":email,"pass":pass}, function(data){
           if (data == "OK"){
               alert("usuario valido");
           }else{
               alert("usuario invalido");
           }
       })
  }
  comprobar_user("prueba@algo.com","123456");
})
```

Que te puede pasar, que no funcione lo que acabo de escribir y es porque te va a arrojar error de Cross Origin, ¿Que quiere decir? Que la pagina.php esta en un determinado dominio y el html de la app en otro distinto. Entonces por seguridad no se ejecutara el post. ¿Como se soluciona? En la pagina de PHP debes agregar un encabezado determinado

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Content-type:application/json")
```

y por ultimo en vez de OK y ERROR tenes que hacer que devuelva un JSON. o sea, {"repuesta":"OK"} o {"repuesta":"ERROR"}

y el codigo modificarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
$(docuement).ready(function(){
  function comprobar_user(email,pass){
       $.post("paginaphpexterna",{"email":email,"pass":pass}, function(data)
       {
           if (data.repuesta == "OK"){
               alert("usuario valido");
           }else{
               alert("usuario invalido");
           }
       })
  }
  comprobar_user("prueba@algo.com","123456");
})
```